# Xamarin iOS 8 , using Auto Layout - Resize images while maintaining the aspect ratio error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a challenge working with images in Xamarin iOS 8. I'm using auto layout and have enabled size classes as well.

I have a table view where I am displaying different images from a server. The images vary in dimension, but regardless of that, I would like to always have them resized to fit the bounds of the cell, without distorting them if they are smaller in size.

This is the function I call, to resize the images:

```
public static UIImage MaxResizeImage(UIImage sourceImage, float maxWidth, float maxHeight)
    {
        var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size;
        var maxResizeFactor = Math.Min(maxWidth / sourceSize.Width, maxHeight / sourceSize.Height);
        if (maxResizeFactor > 1)
            return sourceImage;
        var width = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Width;
        var height = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Height;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new SizeF((float)width, (float)height), false, 2.0f);
        sourceImage.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)width, (float)height));
        var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return resultImage;
    }
```

Challenge:

- Using the **ScaleAspectFit** content mode on the UIImageView on the cell,

  - On the iPhone, if the image is smaller than the width of the screen, there are blank spaces.
  - On the iPad, they all have blank spaces on the sides.

**Aspect Fit iPhone**

[image: iPhone sample - Scale AspectFit in Portrait mode]

**Aspect Fit iPad**

[image: AspectFit iPad Portrait mode]

1. I changed the Content Mode to **ScaleAspectFill**

**AspectFill iPhone portrait mode**

They look okay in portrait mode on the iPhone
 [image]

**AspectFill iPad portrait mode**

They look cut off here and sometimes overlap.
[image]

**AspectFill iPad landscape mode**

They look cut off here and sometimes overlap.

[image]

I tested uploading the same images on Facebook and regardless of the size if the image,it always gets re-sized to fit the width, while the aspect ratio is maintained.

How do I resize the images properly regardless of the device? What content mode is suitable?

**EDIT GetHeightForRow override**

This is how I'm calculating the height of each image.

```
public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        SampleCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (SampleCell.Key) as SampleCell;

        if (cell == null) {

            cell = new SampleCell ();

        }

        nfloat height = 0.0f;

        try {


            if (cell != null) 
            {
                var _url = TableItems[indexPath.Row].Item4;


                //call method to load the images
                if (_url != null)
                {
                    cell.cellImageView.SetImage(
                        url: new NSUrl(_url.AbsoluteUri),
                        placeholder: UIImage.FromBundle("sample.png"),
                        completedBlock: (image,error,type,url)=> {

                            if(image != null)
                            {
                                imageResizer = new ImageResizer(image);

                                imageResizer.RatioResize((float)tableView.Frame.Size.Width,(float)tableView.Frame.Size.Height);
                                UIImage resizedImage = imageResizer.ModifiedImage;

                                cell.cellImageView.Image = image;

                            }


                        }
                    );

                    height = cell.ContentView.SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize (UIView.UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).Height;
                    height += 1;

                }

 }


        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }
        //return 240f;
        return height;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried ScaleAspectFit images inside a table view with dynamic cell height? `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0;`

Comment: In the above example,Yes, I already have that. But I'm returning a fixed height in the GetHeightForRow. Because I'm downloading images from a server, I have also tried calculating the height of each image beforehand, and they look so much better. The only challenge now is with the automatic dimension enabled and getting the height before, the images are spaced out. Not as they appear in the screen shots. The scrolling is now also not smooth, I guess because we're making the calculations and resizing at the same time.

Comment: I have added an edit to show how I'm calculating the height of the images.